# How to validate register settings array

Tags: array, settings-api, validation, callbacks

I would like to know how to perform a proper validation with the `register_setting()` callback function.

Here is a sample part of my code I want to work with:

```
register_setting( 'wpPart_options', 'wpPart_options', array( &$this, 'wpPartValidate_settings' ) );
```

`$this` is an array of objects.

And here is the content of my `wpPartValidate_settings();` function.

```
public function wpPartValidate_settings( $input ) {

   $options = get_option( 'wpPart_options' );
   if ( check_admin_referer( 'wpPart_nonce_field', 'wpPart_nonce_verify_adm' ) ) {
      return $input;
   }

}
```

Since `$input` is an array, how can I perfom a proper validation on every input that comes to the validating function?

I would like, for example, to perform a `strlen()` check on a text field :

```
if ( strlen( $input ) != 20 )
   add_settings_error( 'wpPart_options', 'textField', __( 'TextField incomplete.', 'wpPart' ) , 'error' );
```

Comment: Are you asking how to iterate over an array in PHP? If so then simple [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) should help you out.

Comment: In fact I was asking if validating the inputs this way is the best practice and if not how to do it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I'd do it the same way, since it seems to be the only point where you can examine user input and validate it.

Also, heavily borrowing from code sample in [this excellent article](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-complete-guide-to-the-wordpress-settings-api-part-7-validation-sanitisation-and-input-i/):

```
function wpPartValidate_settings( $input ) {
   if ( check_admin_referer( 'wpPart_nonce_field', 'wpPart_nonce_verify_adm' ) ) {

    // Create our array for storing the validated options
    $output = array();

    foreach( $input as $key => $value ) {

      // Check to see if the current option has a value. If so, process it.
      if( isset( $input[$key] ) ) {

        // Strip all HTML and PHP tags and properly handle quoted strings
        $output[$key] = strip_tags( stripslashes( $input[ $key ] ) );

      } // end if
    } // end foreach
  } // end if
  // Return the array processing any additional functions filtered by this action
  return apply_filters( 'wpPartValidate_settings', $output, $input );
}
```

My favourite part is the `apply_filters` call at the end. Now that's best practice!